# How to set Release Variables scope per Deployment Agent

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

How to set the release variables scope per deployment agent? for example, while setting up IIS Bindings, i need to use different IP on each deployment agent.

we can set Release variable scope per deployment group, but not able to find a way to set at the agent level.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution might be to set the IP on the agent as an environment variable and then [pass the environment variable to the task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=vsts&tabs=designer%2Cpowershell#environment-variables).