# Is there any way of specifying machine specific configuration when using deployment groups is azure devops?

Tags: iis, deployment, azure-devops, web-deployment, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We currently have a number of release pipelines setup in Azure DevOps that use Agent Pools to release web applications to locally managed servers.  I'm looking to update these to use deployment groups, but am struggling with the best way to define machine specific configuration properties.

Specifically, I'm trying to define bindings in IIS on each of the machines in the deployment group before deploying the application.  Each machine has a number of web sites set up in IIS and the bindings for each site will need to use  one of the IP addresses that has been assigned to the machine.

As it stands I have each macine in the deployment group tagged with a unique name (machine name) and then have a separate deployment group job in the release definition to configure the web site using the "IIS Web App Manage" task.  Whilst this works, it means I'm unable to release to multiple machines in parallel, as you would if the deployment group job was to target multiple machines.

Is there something that I'm missing, or am I destined to have separate jobs to configure the machines (which I could turn off I guess to save time if nothing has changed), and then another to deploy the application to all machines?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Release Variables scope per Deployment Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53887231/how-to-set-release-variables-scope-per-deployment-agent)

Comment: The solution for the potential duplicate (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53887231/how-to-set-release-variables-scope-per-deployment-agent), would in theory work, but I'd still be interested to know if there are any other methods that I'm overlooking.